# Derived Queries with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

My task is to compose a query without using the `@Query` annotation.
If you use `select`, it will work, but if you use `update`, then the exception pointing to the line query.executeUpdate();

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

CustomUserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomUserRepository {
    List<User> findByUniqueId(String uniqueId,UserStatus role);
}
```

CustomUserRepositoryImpl:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<User> findByUniqueId(String uniqueId, UserStatus role) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("update User u set u.userStatus=:userStatus where u.unique=:unique");
        query.setParameter("userStatus", role).setParameter("unique", uniqueId);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return query.getResultList();
}
```

ControllerFour:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostMapping
public String replaceStatusPost (@RequestParam("uniqueid") String uniqueid, @RequestParam("userstatus") UserStatus userstatus, Model model) {
        List <User> user = userRepository.findByUniqueId(uniqueid, userstatus);
        model.addAttribute("attz", user);
        return "replaceStatus";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that message says all:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

When using `EntityManager` to execute any update operation (update/insert/delete) you have to do that within transaction.

Therefore your code should look like:

```java
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
// execute any operation on entityManager
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Side note, it is generally recommended to use `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Autowired` as that gives more control over the injected `EntityManager` (especially if you have multiple DB configurations).